# Convert code to/from string

Tags: scheme

MIT Scheme has `string->input-port`, Racket has `open-input-string`. How to implement this in pure Scheme (no Racket, Chicken, Gambit, or any implementation-specific extension).

Comment: Which version are you targeting. The current R6RS or the old R5RS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Chis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19862619/1565698) we have a new Scheme standard, R7RS. It has `open-input-string` provided.

For the older R6RS, it's trivial to implement the same with [make-custom-textual-input-port](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_idx_682) from `(rnrs io ports (6))` library. Here is something I put together:

```
#!r6rs

(import (rnrs base (6))
        (rnrs io ports (6))
        (rnrs mutable-strings (6))
        (rnrs io simple (6)))

(define (open-input-string str)
  ;; might not be so important to have a different indentifier
  ;; but this will make debugging easier if implementations use the 
  ;; id provided
  (define get-id
    (let ((n 0))
      (lambda (str)
        (set! n (+ n 1))
        (string->symbol 
         (string-append "string-port" str "-"
                        (number->string n))))))

  (let ((len (string-length str))
        (pos 0))
    (make-custom-textual-input-port 
     (get-id str)
     (lambda (string start count)
       (let loop ((cur-dst start)
                  (cur-src pos)
                  (n 0))
         (cond ((or (>= cur-src len)
                    (>= n count))
                (set! pos cur-src)
                n)
               (else
                (string-set! string cur-dst (string-ref str cur-src))
                (loop (+ cur-dst 1)
                      (+ cur-src 1)
                      (+ n 1))))))
     (lambda () pos)
     (lambda (new-pos) (set! pos new-pos))
     #f)))

(define test (open-input-string "(1 2 3 4)(5 6 7 8)"))
(define str (read test))  ; str == (1 2 3 4)
(define str2 (read test)) ; str2 == (5 6 7 8)
```

With `R5RS` there is not way to do this except using a file.

Comment: Well, let's do one better: R7RS has recently been ratified, and it has `open-input-string` built in. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I'll be using it the second Ikarus and Racket has support for it :)

Answer (score 1):

In the recently-ratified [R7RS](http://trac.sacrideo.us/wg/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/r7rs.pdf), `open-input-string` is provided directly. (Thanks to Sylwester for reminding me to look beyond R5RS. :-))

---

In R5RS, a pure Scheme implementation of string ports is not trivial, as it requires you to redefine all the standard I/O functions. See [SRFI 6](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-6/srfi-6.html) for a reference implementation.

It really is better if your implementation supports string ports directly.

Answer (score -2):

Write the string to a (temporary) file, then return an input port to read it back in.  Like this:

```
(define (open-input-string string)
  (let ((file "/tmp/foo"))
    (call-with-output-file file
      (lambda (port)
         (display string port)))
    (open-input-file file)))

> (define ps (open-input-string "This is a test; it is only a test"))
> ps
#<input-port (textual) "/tmp/foo">
> (read-line ps)
"This is a test; it is only a test"
```

Note, you'll need to be more sophisticated with use of `file`.  For example, the above code only works once; it will fail with 'file exists' on a second call.  But the above is a simple answer to your question.

Comment: Writing to a fixed temp file is very unsafe, as it opens up avenues for a [symlink attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink_race). To be safe, you'd have to use `mkstemp`, which is not "pure Scheme".

Comment: Thanks.  Not solving the world's problems here; just answering a question for a person in need.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's still a poor solution, akin to telling someone to use `gets` (in C) to read in a string from stdin.